# Fazer filtro em variável carregada do banco no javascript

Tags: javascript, asp

Tenho uma variável, que me trás todos os dados do banco de dados.
Há como, em javascript, eu fazer um filtro nela ainda, tipo ela me trás 10 tuplas e pelo filtro apenas uma.
Antes que alguém diga para fazer isso no banco, gostaria de saber se tem como fazer isso no javascript, somente para aprendizado.

**Edit:**

Como não ficou claro, vou esclarecer.
Há como filtrar um recordset com javascript?
O Sérgio me respondeu por array e filter.
A pergunta era essa. Há como fazer um filtro em um recordset usando javascript puro? Recordset do asp clássico.

Comment: Não entendi direito, mas se você tiver uma variável com dados do banco, você pode facilmente fazer comparações utilizando `var.nome_coluna`: `if (pessoa.cpf.length != 11)`, por exemplo.

Answer (score 2):

A resposta é sim.

Depende um pouco de como tens os dados mas a função [`.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) funciona com Arrays. Se tiveres uma array tudo ok, senão tens de usar `Object.keys(teuObjeto).filter(` e iterar as chaves desse objeto.

#### E como filtrar?

A funcçõ que é passada ao método [`.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) deve ter um `return`. Se esse return der resultado verdadeiro (valor Booleano) então esse elemento fica, se der falso então ele é excluído.

Exemplo;

```
var arrayExemplo = [1, 2, 3, 'foo'];

var novaArray = arrayExemplo.filter(function(elemento, index){
    return typeof elemento == 'string';
});
```

Resultado:

```
console.log(novaArray); // dá ['foo']
```

Ou seja ele filtrou os elementos da array que **não** são do tipo *String*.

Um outro exemplo radical seria:

```
var novaArray = arrayExemplo.filter(function(elemento, index){
    return false;
});
```

Este exemplo dá uma array vazia (`[]`) pois todos os resultados dão `false`.

Comment: Tenho um recordset vindo do Oracle. Preciso filtrar por dois valores que possuo. Cod_Prestador e Tipo_Prestador, por exemplo. Considero o recordset como um array? Acho que não.

Comment: @pnet não sei responder sem ver o código. Recebes isso por ajax? o que dá `console.log(dadosDoOracle);`?